TPopup menus are reversed from left-to-right to right-to-left after D2007 migration
TPopup menu layouts (Icons/Bitmaps, text alignment, three dots...) are reversed from left-to-right to right-to-left after migrating my source code from D7 to D2007.   My system language is English.
I tried to add the new BiDiMode setting like this, but it does not seem to fix the issue.
Any ideas, how to get the menu icons back to the left side?
The popup menu is created like this, without a reference to a form:
Popup = TpopupMenu.create(nil);
Popup.BiDiMode := bdLeftToRight;

   StatisticsItem.Caption := 'menuitemtest1...';
   StatisticsItem.BitMap.Handle := loadbitmap(Hinstance, 'STATISTICS');
   StatisticsItem.OnClick := xxx
   PopUp.Items.insert(0,StatisticsItem);

   StatisticsItem2 := TMenuItem.Create(Popup);
   StatisticsItem2.Caption := 'menuitemtest2...'; 
   ETC...

   TrayIcon.PopupMenu := Popup;



Please add a screenshot from how it looks now (and preferably one from the past), to make sure the terms "reversed" and "left-to-right" aren't interpreted differently.

Cannot reproduce! Please provide a complete [mre]. Also add info about the locale of the machine.

Thanks, I have added more code lines and the screen capture of the bug,  you can see how the menu appears and how the '...' are moved from the end of string to the begin of menu item.

The problem you are describing is not in the sample code. PopupMenu.BidiMode can be used to set the direction of the popup menu. I verified this in Delphi 2009 (I don't have 2007). So if you explicitly set this property and it is not honored, chances are that some other code messes with it.
What you can do is set SysLocale.MiddleEast := False;. This should disable right to left completely. But it might be better to research this a little further.
Enable debug dcu's in your project. Open the unit Menus.pas and set a breakpoint in TMenu.DoBiDiModeChanged. This should tell you where the direction of the menu changes. The line where MenuItemInfo.fType is assigned should be of special interest to you.

SysLocale.MiddleEast := False; solved it!
